# TSocket time out on Thrift Server after working fine for 45 minutes

Tags: php, hadoop, hbase, thrift, ambari

I wrote a script to connect to HBase using Thrift Server. Each minute this script fetches 3200 records from HBase and updates some information and saves it. The first 30-45 minutes this is working fine on the Ambari Hadoop cluster. After that a query exception occurs:

> exception 'Thrift\Exception\TTransportException'
>   with message 'TSocket: timed out reading 4 bytes from 192.168.1.55:9090'
>   in `/home/responsive/thrift/thrift/lib/Thrift/Transport/TSocket.php:274`

To resolve this  error, I restarted the Thrift service and then it is working fine again, but I don't know why this error occurs.

Do you have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Have u set any timeout ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I updated your question, formatting the error message and removing some unnecessary text at the end. Also shortened the title to the essence.

Comment: @SashidharThallam Yes I have set below time out in.Please help me if know this answer.  $socket = new TSocket(THRIFT_HOST, THRIFT_PORT);
 $socket->setSendTimeout(10000); 
 $socket->setRecvTimeout(20000); 
 
 $transport = new TBufferedTransport( $socket );
 $protocol = new TBinaryProtocol( $transport );
 $client = new HbaseClient( $protocol );
 $transport->open();